# javaのprocessKeyEvent

Tags: java

KeyEventの使い方がわかりません。
下記のコードを実行すると

enableEvents(long)はComponentでprotectedアクセスされます

と、エラーがでます。

初歩的な質問だと思いますが検索してもわからず質問しました。
どのように記述したらいいでしょうか。知恵を貸してください・・・

```
public class Sample
{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    javax.swing.JFrame.enableEvents(java.awt.AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
  }
  protected void processKeyEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e){
    System.out.println("キーが押されました");
  }
}
```

Comment: processKeyEventはもう使われてない方法でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`KeyEvent`は、コンポーネントに[KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html)を追加し、大抵の場合そこで使用します。

詳しくは、チュートリアルの[How to Write a Key Listener (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Writing Event Listeners)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)が参考になると思います。

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KeyEventTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
          System.out.println("キーが押されたときに呼び出されます。" + e);
        }
        @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
          System.out.println("キーが離されたときに呼び出されます。" + e);
        }
        @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
          System.out.println("キーがタイプされたときに呼び出されます。" + e);
        }
      });
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: KeyListener使わせていただきます。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

まずキー入力の目的を考えねばなりません。
コードを見る限り、JFrame（画面）に対してキー入力を受け付けたいだけのサンプル的なものだと思われます。
本来であれば他の回答にあるように、コンポーネント外部からキー入力を受け取りたいということなのでKeyListenerを使うべきです。
しかし、何らかの入門書籍やウェブサイトを見てprocessKeyEventを使われたと思いますので、その方法を示します。

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Sample extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample frame = new Sample();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  Sample() {
    enableEvents(AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
  }
  public void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e){
    System.out.println("キーが押されました");
  }
}
```

[processKeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#processKeyEvent-java.awt.event.KeyEvent-)メソッドは、独自のコンポーネントを定義する際に内部的に使用する用途で定義するものです。なので、上記のようにComponentのサブクラス内でオーバーライドしなければなりません。何も継承していないクラスに実装しても意味がありませんし、勝手に呼び出されることもありません。
同様に[enableEvents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#enableEvents-long-)もComponentのサブクラス内から呼び出すものです。protectedになっているのはその為です。

Comment: 勉強になりました！ありがとうございます！